# Sphinx wordform file for English

Tags: sphinx

Is there are any existings wordform file for English irregular verb ?
i.e. i want Sphinx to return same result for find and found.
It seems that i need wordform file because setting morphology = stem_en not seems deal with irregular verb

Comment: Have you tried `morphology=lemmatize_en`?

Comment: it seems like lemmatize_en only possible to use at dev version? When i try at Sphinx 2.1.8-id64-release it say to me "unknown stemmer lemmatize_en; skipped"

Comment: Have you downloaded the `en.pak` file and pointed to it in the config with `lemmatizer_base`?